# Why does my static html page put cookies on the viewer's browser?

Tags: html, cookies, google-api, ovh

I host a simple (static) html page on a subdomain host by OVH. There is nothing else on this subdomain.

The webpage uses standard html things plus a `<img>` tag whose `src` is

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chl=<DATA>
```

---

When inspecting my browser, I found that two cookies are found for this subdomain:

#### First one:

```
Name: 300gpBAK
Content: R4178757645
Host: <my subdomain>
Path: /
Expires: creation time + 1h
```

#### Second one:

```
Name: 300gp
Content: R588125346
Host: <my subdomain>
Path: /
Expires: creation time + 1h11
```

So my question boils down to: **where do they come from? Is it from Google API? Why are they bound to my subdomain instead of `chart.googleapis.com`?**

Comment: Nothing you've described in the question will create a cookie for your subdomain.

Comment: @Quentin So ... is it OVH? Is it linked with the Let's Encrypt certificate?

Comment: SSL certificates do not generate cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very much like a cookie that's been added by the hosting company (OVH).

Looking at https://tools.digitalpoint.com/cookie-search?name=300gp, it reveals about 85 pages of domains that have that cookie set.

Executing `whois` on the IP addresses associated with a couple of these, I always get:

```
inetnum:        213.186.33.0 - 213.186.33.255
netname:        OVH
descr:          OVH SAS
descr:          Shared Hosting Servers
descr:          http://www.ovh.com
country:        FR
```

Comment: I'm felling mildly violated by this intrusive hosting company... Why would they do that?

Comment: No idea... User tracking? Surprised that this is even legal in the EU.

Comment: Ok, now that I know what to look for, I've found an explanation (in french). They are (accordingly to OVH) technical cookies used to redirect viewers in a way that depends on the servers' load. They are reportedly _"not subject to the UE law on cookies"_.